# Is lead glass helpful in protecting against space radiation?

Tags: radiation, materials

I have read that it is better to use materials like polyethylene for protection against space radiation as compared to lead. But I need transparent materials, so lead glass seemed like a good option. I will have a layers of other transparent materials over it, but will lead glass work or will it produced secondary radiation?

Comment: Have you considered using polycarbonate? See also this question about windows on the ISS: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/what-materials-are-the-windows-on-the-us-segment-of-the-iss-made-out-of

Comment: Glass is space is a bad idea.

Comment: Heavy atoms generate secondary radiation when hit. Water and hydrogen gas are both better alternatives, I think, and are both transparent. Maybe lead glass would help in te outside window if the water of such an aquarium window is enoughto stop secondary radiation. But hydrogen is better than the same mass lead, in this respect.

Comment: I have got layers of Titanium Dioxide and Aluminium Oxynitride and conventional glass. Will it stop secondary radiation?

Comment: @GdD: Silicate glass is commonly used for windows in space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found specific research into lead glass for space applications. But the [general principle](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20040086568&hterms=shielding%20performance%20index%20Wilson&qs=N%3D0%26Ntk%3DAll%26Ntt%3Dshielding%2520performance%2520index%2520Wilson%26Ntx%3Dmode%2520matchallpartial) that light atoms are better than heavy ones for shielding against space radiation also applies to lead glass.